# Writing Text To A Specific Point In A Text File C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to write to a spefic location in a text file? I would like to be able to create a template for an email as a text file then change the body based on different parameter values..

EmailBoby.txt..

```
This is an email body.

FirstName: [FirstName]
LastName: [LastName]
```

Can I in code locate [Firstname] and replace it with a value somehow?

Comment: Is there any reason you dont want to use an existing templating library?

Comment: @PaulPhillips Can you elaborate for him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the complete textfile into a string. Then do string replace and save again. Like that

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
fileContent.Replace("[FirstName]", "John");
File.WriteAllText(path, fileContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Files can't be changed that way. you need to rewrite the entire file to accomplish that.
Since Files are a stream, you need all the data before that, and after that to alter the file.